# How to Concatenate results of a column with String as delimiter

Tags: sql-server

I have results from a table as follows:-

```
Name           Cat Type
Waugh, John       1
Waugh, John       2
Sampras, Jim      3
Sampras, Jim      4
```

What I want is this:

```
Name            Cat Type
Waugh, John       1, 2 
Sampras, Jim      3, 4
```

How can I accomplish this ? Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Look for *Group_concat for SQL-Server*

Comment: This link should help you: http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

For t-sql, the best answers are either to use XML PATH or a cte with a numbers table.  See, for instance, this question: [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
SELECT
      T1.Name, 
      [Cat Type] = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10),T2.[Cat Type])
          FROM TableName T2
          WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableName T1
GROUP BY T1.Name
ORDER BY [Cat Type]
```

Result:

```
NAME            CAT TYPE
Waugh, John     1,2
Sampras, Jim    3,4
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec7f3/6).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two values, you can do:

```
select t.name,
       min(t.CatType) + ',' + max(t.CatType) as CatType
from table t
group by t.name;
```

This assumes that `CatType` is a string variable.  If it is a number, you have to convert it to a string.